# C# - Randomizing Linq Items

Tags: c#, linq

How would I randomize linq items?

```
            var words = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
        richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + words);
```

where it has `(Environment.NewLine + words);`
I want to randomize what words is. So for example, these could be outputs:

bcad, ac, da, cab, abb,

for example.

Comment: You are trying to find out possible combination of alphabets. Search for it and you will hopefully get many ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
var newWords = new List<string>();
while(Random.Range(0,someProbability) != 0){
    newWords.Add(words[Random.Range(0,words.Length)]);
}
words = newWords.ToArray();
```

where someProbability determines how long your new words is likely to be.

Comment: I get an error on Range 'Random does not contain a definition for Range'

Comment: My bad. I confused the Unity API with System. Add the line `Random rand = new Random();` to the top, then replace `Random.Range` with `rand.Next` and that should work.

Comment: Thanks, this is better :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this get a random order.

```
Random rand =new Random();
words.OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).ToArray()
```

For deleting you need to figure that out your self. Also looks like you want repeats, but this should get you started.

This will take the top 0 to 4

```
words.OrderBy(x =>rand.Next()).Take(rand.Next(0,4)).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to generate random words would be:

```
public static string RandomString(int length)
{
    const string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
    return new string(
        Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
        .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}
```